# How to manipulate Kafka streams from Memgraph mgconsole?

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb

How can I manipulate Kafka streams from `mgconsole`? By manipulation I mean to start/pause/stop/delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with streams I think that the most important command is `SHOW STREAMS;`. With this command you will find out the name of the streams that you have. You will need a stream name to reference it when you want to stop or start it.

Commands for that are:

- starting the stream: `START STREAM streamName;`
- stopping the stream: `STOP STREAM streamName;`
- deleting the stream: `DROP STREAM streamName;`

I don't think that there is a special command for pausing a stream.